# Lumify demo login details unknown

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, bigdata

I am trying to install lumify demo as per the steps showed in this link:
https://github.com/lumifyio/lumify

I was able to make the virtual machine by using the given commands. 
The problem occurs when I start the virtual machine. It asks me to login. The virtual box display shows "lumify-demo login:" I am unaware of these login details as I have not set any password.

Comment: I imagine that the best approach would be to search the documentation, or, if you are sure the docs do not mention it, raise a ticket on the GitHub issues page.

Comment: thank you @halfer I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Being a vagrant build... login should be 'root' and password should be 'vagrant' as per lots of other good folks Googling for vagrant box passwords.